# (Ocaml) unbound module error on visual code

Tags: ocaml, merlin

I have just started to learn Ocaml.
I'm using visual code as my IDE on Ubuntu,
and I have OCaml extension and merlin installed.

and I have the following problem -

my workspace folder contains only 2 files:
a.ml and b.ml.

In the file a.ml I have defined a module named "COOL", and in the file b.ml I wrote:

```
~ b.ml ~

open COOL;;
```

**I get an error that says "Unbound module COOL merlin"**

Is there any way to make it see the module on file a.ml?
I tried searching for solution, I saw something with makefile and .merlin and B build 
but I didn't understand it, I don't have anything but the 2 files I mentioned.
I would be happy if someone can tell me what exactly should be done in order for this little example to work.

Comment: In OCaml every file is a module, with the module name derived from capitalizing the file name. The contents of `a.ml` will therefore be accessible through the module `A`, meaning you can open your module with `open A.COOL`.

Comment: it's really annoying, but basically if you can't/don't build a file then you won't have access to "go to definition".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl; dr: do `ocamlc -c a.ml` (or whatever your compilation command is) in order to generate the `a.cmi` file that merlin will use to get the list of symbols defined in module `A`.

Apart the fact that in `b.ml` your module is indeed named `A.COOL` (unless you `open A` before `open COOL`) as mentioned by glennsl, the point is that `merlin` is, as far as I know, only watching the current file being edited, i.e. `b.ml` in your case. In order to have access to external symbols, you thus need to have compiled the other files (or at least their corresponding `.mli` if they exist), in order to have the relevant `.cmi` files available to merlin.

This is implicit in the [paragraph](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/project-configuration#b-build-path) of the documentation describing build paths, which says "[merlin] needs to know where to find the cmi files of the other modules of your project", i.e. those files need to exist in the first place.